# Apache 2.4 authentication combination with LDAP and htpassword

Tags: ldap, authentication, apache-2.4, mod-auth-ldap, digest

We use Apache with mod_svn to serve our Subversion repositories. Previously we used file based authentication with *AuthType* **Digest** set. We want to move to *LDAP*-based authentication, but at the first time we'd like to have the old and the new authentication to work side-by-side.

The problem is *LDAP* doesn't support **Digest** authentication type but only **Basic**. I found the **AuthBasicUseDigestAlgorithm** Apache directive to be able to use our current digest auth file with **Basic** authentication type, but this breaks the LDAP auth saying:

```
    AH02493: Authn provider does not support AuthBasicUseDigestAlgorithm
```

Is there a way to have these two authentication method to work together somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question it isn't possible to mix these two types of authentication methods this way with Apache. So I turned to use SCM-Manager which is capable (with a little patch) to handle this situation.